# How to sort filenames witch contains numbers

Tags: bash, sorting

I have a list of filenames, `cat mylist.txt`:

```
myfile.txt
myfile.version2.txt
myfile.version.tab.txt
```

If I use in Python `sorted()` function, I have this result (that what I except):

```
myfile.txt
myfile.version.tab.txt
myfile.version2.txt
```

I would like to have the same in Bash, result of `cat mylist.txt | sort -V`:

```
myfile.txt
myfile.version2.txt
myfile.version.tab.txt
```

Result of `cat mylist.txt | sort`:

```
myfile.txt
myfile.version2.txt
myfile.version.tab.txt
```

It's not what I expect. How can I sort properly with the most generic way?
For example, imagine that one day I will have this in my list:

```
myfile.version.tab2.txt
myfile.version.tab.txt
```

Comment: just skip the -V?  cat mylist.txt | sort

Comment: Unrelated side note: [UUOC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_%28Unix%29#Useless_use_of_cat) is better avoided, e.g. `sort < mylist.txt`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Locale issue? Try:

```bash
$ LC_ALL=C sort mylist.txt
myfile.txt
myfile.version.tab.txt
myfile.version.tab2.txt
myfile.version2.txt
```

Comment: Thanks it works! Could you develop the answer? Why we need to add this? I will validate your answer after explication.

Comment: Well, you want a comparison that uses the natural order of bytes (C locale) not the order of your particular locale (which we don't know) that may be different. Compare, for instance, with `LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 sort mylist.txt` and see that the US English locale orders characters differently than C.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure about your issue? I have done a test and this is my result:

```
cat mylist.txt | sort
version.txt
version2.txt

cat mylist.txt | sort -V
version.txt
version2.txt

echo $SHELL
/bin/bash
```

I've done my test on a Ubuntu app:

```
uname -a
Linux name 4.4.0-19041-Microsoft #1237-Microsoft Sat Sep 11 14:32:00 PST 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Yes I am sure about the result, I just updated the question. Your file content is not the same as mine. This is the reason why you obtain the excepted result.

Answer (score 0):

Sorting tools (such as `sort` and also `ls`) respect locale settings. A simple example:

```bash
cd "$(mktemp -d)"
touch cheetah gecko hamster iguana
ls
```

What will be the output from `ls` above? Let’s see:

```
$ LC_COLLATE=cs_CZ.UTF-8 ls
gecko  hamster  cheetah  iguana
$ LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8 ls
cheetah  gecko  hamster  iguana
```

In the original question, this boils down to how the locale’s collation rules compare `2` against `.`, i.e. which one is “greater”.